# Search does not default to all objects in Customer Portal (see screenshots)

Tags: administration

In Customer Portal, my search component defaults to search a particular object, **based on the most recent search**.

[image]

What should I do, so that every Customer Portal page should have this component to **Search All** objects, irrespective of the most recent object searched?

[image]

Comment: Barney, are you using the standard portal functionality or Visualforce?

Comment: @WesNolte, I am using **standard** Customer Portal with the standard home page search component. It looks customized in the screenshot because I have introduced a CSS in *Header*. I would say that my requirement is not possible out-of-the-box, and if possible anyhow, may require dirty JavaScripting in *Header*.

Comment: Exactly :) Sorry about that buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This requirement is not possible OOTB.

(If possible anyhow, may require introducing dirty JavaScript in the **Customer Portal Header HTML**. Such hacks are dirty because it involves tinkering around with HTML elements using JavaScript, by their HTML IDs. Since the HTML IDs are not documented by Salesforce, they can change the ID names in any release without informing the public, thereafter rendering the *hack* as broken. Hence, these dirty hacks are not future-proof.)